# CMS for Professional Photographer with Pretty Admin Back End

Tags: content-management-system, gallery, photo-gallery, photography, photo-management

I'm working on a few sites for professional photographers who want to be able to update on their own. I'm looking for a simple CMS solution that has very basic functionality as a gallery and is easy for them to work with. My main concern is with ordering images--I'd like for them to be able to drag their thumbnails around and lock the order. I suspect there is an existing solution out there and am looking for recommendations. I've seen something like this driven by Flash for Flash sites, but I don't know the name of it. I'm looking for something that is similar, but not Flash.

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Answer (score 1):

Photogallery tikiti is nice http://www.rocky.nu/photogallery/

Answer (score 1):

I used wordpress and the dm_albums plugin for this site http://www.arkphotography.co.uk

I found dm_albums easy to use, and so did the photographer who had little experience of using wordpress and none of using dm_albums.